# Actualizar datos de un formulario de acuerdo a un registro de una tabla html

Tags: javascript, php, html

El problema es que al realizar la actualización de los datos del formulario, lo hace correctamente, pero deja de funcionar el **menú principal** y la **barra de navegación**. Yo lo tengo asi...

```
<tbody >
 <?php
  while($fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($consultaVendedores)){
   $numVende=$fila['no_vende'];
   $nom=$fila['nombre'];
   $rfc=$fila['rfc'];
 ?>
 <tr id="fila" onclick="alerta(<?php echo $numVende;?>);"  >
  <th id="no_vende" ><?php echo $numVende; ?></th>
  <th id="nombre"><?php echo $nom; ?></th>
  <th id="rfc"><?php echo $rfc; ?></th>
 </tr>       
 <?php 
  }
 ?>      
</tbody>
```

Este es el fragmento de la tabla en la cual yo mando a llamar una funcion llamada `alerta`, y le envío el número de vendedor.

```
function alerta(id){
 $("#info").load('datosVende.php?id='+id);
}
```

Esta es la función en la cual manda a cargar la página `datosVende.php` en la que solo actualizo el `div` con `id=info`, haciendo la consulta, pero ahora de esta forma...

```
$NumeroVende= $_GET['id'];
 <?php
  /* -----PRIMER REGISTRO----- */
  $consultaPrimerVende="SELECT * FROM aavende where no_vende=$NumeroVende";
  $queryPrimerVende=sqlsrv_query($conn,$consultaPrimerVende);
  $fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryPrimerVende);
  $no_vende=$fila['no_vende'];
  $nombre=$fila['nombre'];
  $rfc=$fila['rfc']; 
  $direccion1=$fila['direccion1'];
  $direccion2=$fila['direccion2'];
  $ciudad=$fila['ciudad'];    
  $estado=$fila['estado'];    
  $tel1=$fila['telefono1'];
  $tel2=$fila['telefono2'];
 ?>
```

Todo lo demas lo dejo tal como está en `catalogoVendedores.php`, pero no me funciona el menú principal y la barra de navegación... Ya probé poniendo el código del menú principal y la barra de navegación en la de `datosVende.php`, pero ni así funciona.

[image: catalogoVendedores.php]

Lo que está marcado con cuadros azules es lo que no funciona al actualizar los datos del vendedor.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54402/discussion-on-question-by-damian-actualizar-datos-de-un-formulario-de-acuerdo-a).

Answer (score 1):

tres cosas:

1) Si estas desarrollando con firefox, te recomiendo instalar firebug, es muy util para hacer seguimiento y te muestra los errores en consola, en este caso, si algun script genero error, firebug te lo mostrara

2) Si colocas codigo nuevo (como el que te pidieron), intenta editar tu post original y agregarlo abajo, indicando esto

3) Me da la impresion de que puede que no sea un error javascript, me explico, tu tienes tu pagina cargada, y actualizas una seccion de esta, la cual tu JQuery ya no tiene la "referencia" por decirlo de una manera simple, normalmente cuando tienes secciones dinamicas en las cuales se deba hacer "click" o alguna accion sobre esta, se agrega ese evento en un **on** de JQuery

```
$( "#id-del-elemento" ).on( "click", function() {
  //Accion a ejecutarse
});
```

Esto te permite que cualquier seccion que se cargan dinamicamente, sean reconocidas por JQuery (intente explicarlo lo mas simple posible)

Referencia: http://api.jquery.com/on/

En resumen, verifica el punto 1, si no es un error de javascript, entonces puede que sea el punto 3.

Saludos

**EDITO:**

El error finalmente se debia a que se tenia una pagina principal en la cual se cargaba todo, pero al ingresar a una seccion, por ejemplo, Catalogo de Vendedores, y se hacia click en un registro de la grilla, por debajo se ejecutaba un ajax que cargaba la pagina nuevamente y la incluia, lo que generaba que se cargaran N veces los mismos JS, en resumen, tenia tantos JS ejecutandose que el navegador se mareaba. La **solucion** fue centralizar y limpiar las secciones dinamicas para que cargaran solo los formularios y/o datos, y todos los CSS y JS quedaron en la master page o pagina principal, asi, solo se cargan una vez y todas las secciones dinamicas las ocupan.

Comment: instale lo que me dijiste pero no me sale ningun error, y por lo que pude observar solo es al hacer clic la primera vez en algun registro de la tabla, ya que despues selecciono otro y ya funciona el boton que compacta el menu y el del perfil del usuario, pero el menu principal sigue sin dejar seleccionar

Comment: ya lo volvi a probar y es de vez en cuando, cuando funciona todo u.u

Comment: Tienes tu sitio montado en algun hosting en donde se pueda revisar? porque... esto de que "funciona de vez en cuando" pues... tu comprenderas que nadie podra decirte que es sin revisarlo

Comment: No no lo tengo en ningun hosting solamente local, subo los archivos a la nube y pongo el enlace aqui?

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!IQUiyBiL!6hQqu3_RXelyTvFXJRLTeyATJXYqYfUSQnX6PotXe2U

Comment: Lo baje, ahora lo reviso, si quieres puedes eliminar el enlace ya

Comment: ok una cosa como elimino el enlace jeje

Comment: Al colocar el mouse encima de tu comentario, al lado derecho aparece una X, al presionarlo te preguntara si deseas eliminar tu comentario.

Comment: Así no es como se debería compartir información en SOes.

Comment: Ariel y @Damian: Considern usar el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) en lugar de los comentarios. Los comentarios son para criticar/solicitar clarificación de preguntas/respuestas, las preguntas sobre como funciona el sitio se debería realizar en [meta].